# Unable to use QtSqlDriver to retrieve data from a table with "." in column names

Tags: sqlite, qt, escaping, pyqt

I have a SQlite database I'm trying to read with the QtSql.QSqlTableModel.  The issue is it won't read any table where the field name contains a "." via the setTable method.

As an example if I have table called MyTable with the column names
(ID, Name.First, Name.Last)
I can manually select it with the query

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

or

```
SELECT "ID", "Name.First", "Name.Last" and all is ok
```

However, the QSqlTableModel won't use that query but will error out with "no such column Name.First Unable to execute statement."

When I dug a little deeper the SQLITE driver in Qt would rewrite the query as

```
SELECT "ID", "Name"."First", "Name"."Last" FROM MyTable
```

But this SELECT statement is wrong and would try and grab columns from another table "Name" but I want a column called "Name.First" in the table "MyTable"

I tried to circumvent this by subclassing the setTable method which worked for getting the data into the TableView:

```
def tableName(self):
    return self._tableName

def setTable(self, tableName):
    self.clear()
    self._tableName = tableName
    self.setQuery(QtSql.QSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM {0}".format(tableName), self.database()))
```

However, reimplementing the method in this fashion broke the method `submitAll()`.

Inside the File Save method I have the following:

```
ok = self.tableModel.submitAll()
if not ok:
    logging.error('Error %s' % self.tableModel.lastError().text())
    logging.error('Error %s' % self.tableModel.query().lastQuery())
    return False
```

This gives this log:

```
ERROR:root:Error near "SET": syntax error Unable to execute statement
ERROR:root:Error SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

But when I don't reimplement the `setTable` method, `submitAll()` works without errors.

So... How do I circumvent the "." in the Column name problem and also have the submitAll() work?

BTW: I agree that having "." in the field names for SQL tables is not a good idea but this is pairing up with another tool that generates the sqlite file in this manner which I have no control over.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-7565.html

http://www.qtforum.org/article/11245/sqlite-how-to-insert-text-that-contains-character-in-field.html

Looks like you just need to call one or both of the functions below before sending it to the database, in order to sanitize the input.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#bindValue

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#prepare

http://xkcd.com/327/

:)

Hope that helps.